# c# method not found exception

Tags: c#, reflection

I know this question is asked allot but a can't find where i am doing wrong. I am using reflection to execute methods on a web service GetProduct and RequestLicence methods.
Those two methods are very similar.

Method in Web Service :

```
[WebMethod]
public LYS.RegistryService.ProductResponse GetProduct(string productNo)
{
  LYS.RegistryService.ProductResponse r = new LYS.RegistryService.ProductResponse();
  return r;
}
```

Code i am using to call web service

```
public ServiceResponseBase GetProduct(string productCode)     
{
   object obj = _WebServiceAssembly.CreateInstance("RegisteryService");
   Type typ = obj.GetType();
   object o = typ.InvokeMember(
      "GetProduct", 
      System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, 
       null, obj, new object[] { productCode });
   return InstantiateObject<ProductResponse>(o);
}
```

The code above is working fine. Here is the part i am getting error.

```
[WebMethod]
public LYS.RegistryService.ServiceResponse RequestLicence(LYS.BusinesObjects.Customer c, string productCode, bool isDemoLicence, bool isProductLicence)
{
  LYS.RegistryService.ServiceResponse r = new LYS.RegistryService.ServiceResponse();
  return r;
}

public ServiceResponseBase RequestLicence(LYS.BusinesObjects.Customer c, string productCode, bool isDemoLicence, bool isProductLicence)
      {
        object obj = _WebServiceAssembly.CreateInstance("RegisteryService");
        Type typ = obj.GetType();
        object o = typ.InvokeMember("RequestLicence", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj, new object[] { c, productCode, isDemoLicence, isProductLicence });
        return InstantiateObject<ServiceResponse>(o);
      }
```

I am getting method not found exception exception at:

```
object o = typ.InvokeMember("RequestLicence", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj, new object[] { c, productCode, isDemoLicence, isProductLicence });
```

Those two functions are very similar and the returning types of those two methods in web service are derived from same interface. So doing same work returning same objects but one is working but the other is not.

Is anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to try:

- Create the object array before calling typ.InvokeMember. This will help to isolate the source of the problem.

  object[] args = new object[] { c, productCode, isDemoLicence, isProductLicence };
- Pass the args parameter to the type.InvokeMember method
- If it still is not working, verify that all of the parameter data types are correct.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So is that all is there no one else to say something.